# Neo4J soft delete user account not working with OPTIONAL MATCH?

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am trying to soft delete nodes in Neo4J when a user soft deletes their account but when I perform the operation by soft deleting a User account without posts or comments the user node is not set to true.

In this case a User account may or may not have any post or comment nodes so I want to perform an OPTIONAL MATCH on those nodes and if any posts or comments are found, I need to set deleted = true for ALL posts and if any comments are found, I need to DETACH DELETE all of the comments.

Even if an account has no posts or comments I need the query to set deleted = true on the matched user object.

What am I doing wrong? How can I made the user node's property be set to true with the below query?

```
import neo4j from "neo4j-driver"

const softDeleteAccount = async (userId) => {

  let driver = neo4j.driver(
    process.env.NEO4J_URL,
    neo4j.auth.basic(process.env.NEO4J_USERNAME, process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD)
  )

  let session = driver.session()

  try {
    let query = `
          MATCH (user:User {userId: $userId})       
          OPTIONAL MATCH (posts:Post {userId: $userId})        // User may not have any posts
          OPTIONAL MATCH (comments:Comment {userId: $userId})  // User may not have any comments
          WITH user, posts, comments
          SET posts.deleted = true, user.deleted = true 
                            // ^ for all posts & user, set deleted = true
          DETACH DELETE comments         // Delete comments & their relationships
          `
    await session.executeWrite((tx) =>
      tx.run(query, {
        userId,
      })
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)

    // return error
  } finally {
    await session.close()
  }

  // on application exit:
  await driver.close()
}

export { softDeleteAccount }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure you pass the value of this parameter as {userId: userId}

```
  tx.run(query, {
    userId: userId,
  })
```

I tried your query by itself and it works well.